# Error with i18n (Error: You are passing an undefined module! Please check the object you are passing to i18next.use())

Tags: gatsby, react-i18next

I am trying to setup i18n in my Gatsby project.

I've been following this tutorial step by step:

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/blog/2017-10-17-building-i18n-with-gatsby/

First I download the required packages:

```
npm i -S i18next i18next-xhr-backend i18next-browser-languagedetector react-i18next
```

Then I set up the i18n component

```
import i18n from "i18next"
import Backend from "i18next-xhr-backend"
import LanguageDetector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector"
import { reactI18nextModule } from "react-i18next"

i18n
.use(Backend)
.use(LanguageDetector)
.use(reactI18nextModule)
.init({
    fallbackLng: "en",

    // have a common namespace used around the full app
    ns: ["translations"],
    defaultNS: "translations",

    debug: true,

    interpolation: {
    escapeValue: false, // not needed for react!!
    },

    react: {
    wait: true,
    },
})

export default i18n
```

Imported it in my layout component:

```
import React from "react"
import "./layout.scss"
import NavMenu from "./NavMenu/navMenu"
import i18n from './i18n/i18n'

export default function Layout({ children }) {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <NavMenu />
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

However, when I run my app I get the following error:

[image]

Does anyone have a clue what the problem might be?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The import from `react-i18next` is wrong. It should be

`import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next"`

and

`.use(initReactI18next)`

If you attempt to import something that is not exported the value is undefined and then `use` gives you the message you're seeing.

It seems to have been called `reactI18nextModule` in an earlier version of `react-i18next` which is why you can find tutorials using it.

I made a [demonstration of the exports in RunKit](https://runkit.com/ehrencrona/i18nextimport)