# Jest - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') when using i18next

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, next.js, i18next

I'm quite new to testing and I'm using i18next in my app but when I try to test components where I use .map() I receive an error of cannot read properties of undefined. How should I write the test so I don't get this error?

Component.js -  the myArr is from a json file.

```
MyComponent = () => {
return(
  <div data-testid="comp">
    {t("myArr", { returnObjects: true}).map(({ name, href, target }) => (
                <div key={name} >
                    <Link href={href}>
                        <a 
                            target={target}
                            onClick={() => handleClick()}>
                            {name}
                        </a>
                    </Link>
                </div>
            ))}
 )
}
```

Component.test.js

```
import React from "react";
import {render } from "@testing-library/react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";

import MyComp from ".";

jest.mock("next/router", () => ({
    useRouter() {
        return {
            local: "",
            asPath: "",
        };
    },
}));


describe("MyComp", () => {
    it("should render myComponent", () => {
        const { getByTestId } = render(
            <myComponent menuOpen={false} setBurgerOpen={jest.fn()} t={jest.fn()}/>
        );

        const myComp = getByTestId("comp");

        expect(myComp).toBeVisible();
        
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you looked at: https://react.i18next.com/misc/testing ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71532601/error-you-are-passing-an-undefined-module-please-check-the-object-you-are-pas/71542618#71542618